# image_tag not working in ActionView FormBuilder helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

I added a `language_select` method to the ActionView form builder:

```
# app/helpers/form_helper.rb
class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper

  def language_select(method, options = {}) 
    image_tag("language-flags/16/en.png")
  end
end
```

The problem is `image_tag` returns an image to `/images/language-flags/16/en.png` which does not exist. I do have an image in `app/assets/images/language-flags/16/fr.png` but it not served trough the Sprockets middleware. Everywhere else `image_tag` works properly.

After looking at Rails’ sources, it seems this is the standard behavior of `image_tag` and, more precisely, `asset_path` and that Sprockets actually modify this behavior to include, for example, the file digest. It seems this modification of `asset_path` is not available in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to call the view helpers (like `image_tag`) on the `@template` attribute in the context of the form builder.

```
def language_select(method, options = {}) 
  @template.image_tag("language-flags/16/en.png")
end
```